# Tableview header label alignment on center

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, alignment, constraints

The label title alignment is left, but i wish centered. 
Whats is wrong with my constraint ?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    var title: UILabel = UILabel()

    title.text = sectionsArray[section]
    title.textColor = UIColor(red: 77.0/255.0, green: 98.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    title.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 225.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 251.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(10)

    var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["label": title])

    title.addConstraints(constraint)

    return title
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you probably need to set the textAlignment property of your UILabel. Even if it's centered I think the text is defaulting to left alignment.

```
title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

In **Swift 4** Center has been renamed to lowercase.

```
title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```